# starting a new job but receiving a better offer dilemma

Tags: new-job, career-switch

I have recently been unemployed after being made redundant. I had a couple of interviews in the space of a few days with one being successful and being offered the job later the same day and I had accepted it due to the fact I was running out of funds and needed to pay bills/and support my family.

A week later after starting the job I receive an offer for another company that was in the same interview space, that has a better career prospects and is much closer commute etc and generally a better offer than the one I have accepted and been there for a week.

My dilemma is how do I tell the company that I want to leave to a better offer?

Comment: @HorusKol - "I have tentatively accepted another offer" seems to me to be very different from "I've actually been working at the company a week already".

Comment: @AndyT - the words in the question may be different - but the answers there, and the answers to the other duplicates all pretty much answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're in your probationary period? You can tell them as little or as much as you like. You hand in your notice as per your contract stating your last day of employment.

Since you've been there such a short time after a period of unemployment there isn't really any need to even put this on your employment record. There is very little to be gained using them as a reference anyway.

You might be burning a bridge with them but that is probably unavoidable however you sugar the pill.

The probation period isn't just for the company, it allows the employee to walk away from a job that isn't a good fit.

Comment: I am interested why someone down voted this. If you've a different opinion add an alternative answer or provide me a reason why this is a 'bad' course of action so I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that you are in a good dilemma. Being made redundant, and having to be unemployed create stress on the mind. Hence, it was logical on your part to take the job offer.

Note that had the first company valued you highly they could have made you an offer at market rate. I am guessing that the reason you were able to close a better offer so much faster is because the first offer was below market rate.

Having said this, morally and legally you are not liable to continue with the company just because you have spent a week with them (I am presuming there is no contract that you have signed).

You should politely, and professionally inform your reporting manager that you have another offer in hand and would like to leave. If at all, your manager wants to discuss (don't bring it up first), you should give him the chance to negotiate and counter offer.

Companies behave like rational agents when making offers, because their stakes in it are often quite low.

You need to focus on getting the best career and job that you can.